# Socket Server in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently, I have a socket server, that listens to incoming connections on two ports (e.g. 7777 and 7778) and replies to them. The data is stored in an RDS environment, part of a bigger Elastic Beanstalk environment that accesses the same data. The socket server is implemented as a Windows service. So far, so good. It works.

However, I am asking myself, whether it's possible to have the socket server also within the same (or possibly another) Elastic Beanstalk environment, but so far, I haven't found any way to do that.

My goals are

1. to have a far simpler deployment procedure, as in the productive environment, I need the socket servers to be behind a load balancer and don't want to deploy a windows service on each instance.
2. to have only one environment to deploy to, so that I won't have to deploy (manually or automatically) each time I have a change in the DAL.

The socket server does *not* need to be implemented as a Windows service, it just is now.

Everything is implemented in C#. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I got this covered. However, I couldn't deploy the Windows Service without errors stand-alone, but only as part of a Web application. Not a real problem in my scenario, though.

I have two projects for this scenario; a Web Application and a Windows Service application.

1. On the build server, I create a ZIP file of the Windows Service
   executables (using `zip.exe`)
2. On the build server, I upload the ZIP file to an S3 bucket (using `s3.exe`)
3. On the project of the **web application**, I create a `.ebextensions` directory
4. In the `.ebextensions` directory, I have a `whatever.config` file that

   1. Takes the ZIP file from S3 and unpacks it onto the C-Drive in my preferred directory
   2. Calls a batch file (part of the ZIP file) that uninstalls and reinstalls the Windows Service with the `InstallUtil.exe` utility (part of the .Net framework)
5. In my nightly builds (of the complete solution), I deploy the **web application** to Elastic Beanstalk using `awsdeploy.exe`.

   - Therefore, I point to a `configuration.txt` file in a `builds` directory of my **web application**.
   - You can generate such a build file with a manual Elastic Beanstalk deployment from Visual Studio; but they are quite easy after a while.

What happens now, is that in my Nightly Builds the Web application is deployed to the Elastic Beanstalk environment; the deployment will recognize that there is a configuration and will execute the steps mentioned below step 4 above. As the Nightly Build created and uploaded the ZIP file of the Windows Service before that, I am sure that I will install the most recent Windows Service.

My only problem now is that the Windows Service does not always install itself because of the infamous *marked for deletion* error. But that's another story.

I hope this helps somebody. If anyone has a suggestion to simplify this, he's welcome to add a comment.